# Apps that have just gone free or are going to?

Tags: ios-appstore

Is there any way to know ahead of time which paid apps are going free, or does Apples RSS feed actually contain data for apps that have just gone free "today" ?

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of Apps which provide a daily list of free Apps. These kind of companies base their business in agreements with the developers, who pay for their Apps to be featured on these App-of-the-Day *lists*.

So, the **Company** makes it's business, the **Developer's App** get notoriety and publicity, which means that on the long shot more people will download the App once it's paid again and the user gets to get free Apps daily. It's a *win-win-win*.

The best and easies way of knowing of paid Apps going free for limited time is using some of these Apps.

Answer (score 1):

I use a a free app called Apps Gone Free which is updated daily with a list (likely not comprehensive) of apps that are free now or for a limited time.

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/apps-gone-free-best-daily/id470693788

No relation to the developer, I just use the app from time to time.

Comment: But do they find those free apps manually, or is there some kind of data from Apple that tells you that app had just gone free?

Comment: Not sure, you will likely have to ask them... ;-)

Comment: I could be wrong but I suspect companies that do that aren't going to be forthcoming with how they collect their data so that's why I thought I'd ask here :)

Answer (score 1):

http://www.macappdeals.com/ also this site lists discounts on app prices.

Answer (score 0):

Apple provide [RSS feeds for their Mac App Store and App Store content](http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/blog/introduction---rss-feed-generator.html). These feeds are used by other sites and services for finding free offerings, price changes, and new releases.

See http://rss.itunes.apple.com to create your own custom feed.

Apple's feeds are not able to directly answer your needs, but the additional filtering can be added by a wide range of other applications or services; or you could create your own with a scripting language.

Answer (score 0):

This is the most extensive list of apps on sale I've found

https://www.jucktion.com/forum/apps-gone-free/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/317692)